# Remove characters from column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to remove "0" and ":" from a column in a dataframe. The code I use is,

```
df_Main["Call Length"].str.replace(":", "")
df_Main["Call Length"].str.replace("0", "")
df_Main
```

Output:

[image]

The result does not remove "0" and ":" How can I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing to assignment of the replacement back to the original column:

```
df_Main["Call Length"] = df_Main["Call Length"].str.replace(":", "")
df_Main["Call Length"] = df_Main["Call Length"].str.replace("0", "")
df_Main
```

Though you can carry out this operation with only one application of `replace`:

```
df_Main["Call Length"] = df["Call Length"].str.replace("[:0]+", "", regex=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would chain the two operations

```
df_Main["Call Length"].str.replace(":", "").str.replace("0", "")
```